# iphone - App crash while starting - Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, three20

I have a crash when starting the app in iOS 3.0 (the app works fine with iOS 3.1 and above).
The app has Three20 v1.0.5 and is compiled with Xcode 4.0.2 
Below is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 3E43A69E-2546-4FF5-B0F0-87A2C839E909
CrashReporter Key:   24f9d24e6874aa655c34a1243e66a2fa839fdaea
Process:         MyApp [1109]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A09581D8-1464-4A8C-B1EC-E366C0E67126/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-06-17 09:43:36.180 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000010
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3000e114 _read_images + 1248
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3000d6b4 map_images + 860
2   dyld                            0x2fe04f0c dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) + 868
3   dyld                            0x2fe0510c dyld::registerImageStateBatchChangeHandler(dyld_image_states, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*)) + 168
4   dyld                            0x2fe09534 dyld_register_image_state_change_handler + 88
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d4a1d0 dyld_register_image_state_change_handler + 84
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3000d32c _objc_init + 32
7   dyld                            0x2fe0e9e0 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 208
8   dyld                            0x2fe0c310 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int) + 372
9   dyld                            0x2fe0c278 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int) + 220
10  dyld                            0x2fe0c278 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int) + 220
11  dyld                            0x2fe0c694 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 48
12  dyld                            0x2fe02814 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 124
13  dyld                            0x2fe08234 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) + 2304
14  dyld                            0x2fe018fc dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long) + 888
15  dyld                            0x2fe01048 _dyld_start + 32

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000028      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x0016e000
    r4: 0x00194dac    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000022      r7: 0x2fffeb38
    r8: 0x0016efbc    r9: 0x00000028     r10: 0x00000027     r11: 0x000001c0
    ip: 0x00051000    sp: 0x2fffeafc      lr: 0x0016e000      pc: 0x3000e114
  cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x16dfff +MyApp armv6  <9d94d8fb9a6b37da8192bb037205f2da> /var/mobile/Applications/A09581D8-1464-4A8C-B1EC-E366C0E67126/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <384bf84ebe2b822c3cb75fce3e8647d6> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30000000 - 0x30008fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <b404b5f84fa4293f0dd35a469b8b6894> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3000c000 - 0x3015bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <92636cf8b8e8f3c10721667c48ca182b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x301ca000 - 0x301d8fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <bb2c65d59f36ea2ffdf39aa4d8e49430> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x301fd000 - 0x302a8fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <3e02f5628a56bce4c9eb1c5e49c863d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3036e000 - 0x3038dfff  Bom armv6  <e126f820dc5fc447dafc66aaab19914a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30501000 - 0x305f5fff  Foundation armv6  <c4fc557994aee708dd4fb14ed4fd875f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3071d000 - 0x30729fff  CoreVideo armv6  <5404da375ad190f3e1404e5e8a70f764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3073a000 - 0x30760fff  AppSupport armv6  <1baa1e22eb94eb405d724a2f6b219f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30778000 - 0x3077dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <e4f0b16194fac3bd426e679a3c35c38b> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x308ed000 - 0x31521fff  UIKit armv6  <73cf70d65e1afef2a6ae94fb81bf2fe4> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x316ff000 - 0x31778fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <d3e22e0639428351c4b80a5fa19f7401> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31885000 - 0x318d1fff  IOKit armv6  <56ba629c062ac21a045914430412c5f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x318e9000 - 0x31aa2fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <80bccae4ab17a49f7fc3a66bb2def894> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31af1000 - 0x31b58fff  CFNetwork armv6  <863076d9b768c76272e3f0f686ca355d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31bb2000 - 0x31bc8fff  OpenGLES armv6  <2c30348868df45d3b8e0e398e0e4f727> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31bcf000 - 0x31cccfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <619918c7282aa5b53ac3ad32c320b7a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31d46000 - 0x31e69fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <f8d95df9776974bbe640911fee96c59d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31ea9000 - 0x31feffff  AudioToolbox armv6  <cd7d22e01299f0d589878c2417c7ff18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32041000 - 0x3204bfff  GraphicsServices armv6  <99b0baa68c257ca5d2fed21bd409ea20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32056000 - 0x32081fff  CoreLocation armv6  <c9dfb15c2c08ee0cc0dcdd70ae3c2c3b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3209b000 - 0x320cefff  Security armv6  <34c21a865d91e9a13477e9395c516f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x320e8000 - 0x32194fff  ImageIO armv6  <44921d26b2b796c2c707c87c68026b16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x321b3000 - 0x321d9fff  MobileSync armv6  <784e8d709e4dcd3306c6925ad711e629> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x322ce000 - 0x32324fff  GMM armv6  <7c7d388ae4af338af7502a21902977e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32369000 - 0x3239cfff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <c295ae48e7c85c02ae396f3dae1901df> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x323b8000 - 0x323bdfff  ITSync armv6  <6f40b01e64146f50f6c31ad1cd7b17f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x324c6000 - 0x32521fff  CoreAudio armv6  <a3189b3cffe9fdb8007e8a4fd54b28e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x325b2000 - 0x325cefff  AddressBook armv6  <3023a336aec321324b5a310ee66687f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32709000 - 0x32740fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <6ef5cd342dee1dcb8d53a54658aee417> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32773000 - 0x3282afff  Message armv6  <eee80a69c511469dacda86ea4abc5cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x328a1000 - 0x328dffff  MessageUI armv6  <7c4f809b7c62a5b3f99fd093d53b9899> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x32906000 - 0x32915fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <3c13b54df1282878fe8dfe5f4fd7e6bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3291c000 - 0x329c4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <1cf2a12e661e1a49f90553b013283b29> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32a0f000 - 0x32a11fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <eded24caed1de0629bce554de6618644> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32a16000 - 0x32a16fff  CoreSurface armv6  <2c60135f696b1a787443c4a68e1aced2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32a1b000 - 0x32a1cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <05aa0565d0f6813003dc5dc175af6048> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32a38000 - 0x32a73fff  Calendar armv6  <bad4a9d669b2597059424e547eeec039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Calendar.framework/Calendar
0x32e0c000 - 0x32f0dfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <3f78cbbe6b5b7d3b4c5753627fcebdee> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x330d8000 - 0x330e3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <8e880791fc827ae2cb63cad8f6ce5d7b> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3311e000 - 0x33213fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <3398aecf5ef07d7bbe6673fc9ab570fb> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x332c9000 - 0x33372fff  WebKit armv6  <d5aabd50737ee994787181afaf83c81e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x333d1000 - 0x3341bfff  Celestial armv6  <96b1b3694ad778d3ae6731646fcfdd8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3358f000 - 0x3363bfff  DataAccess armv6  <5cbeac5522cbe75e90c99906b5b5ae05> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3389a000 - 0x3389dfff  MobileInstallation armv6  <f886e8377d1af59ff0c99469e8b1b105> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3415c000 - 0x34165fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <4997adf422af4a9eecf25aa9bcaf8fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3416c000 - 0x341fcfff  MapKit armv6  <36c6030a2847ef50e5b8de976f6cb685> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x346e9000 - 0x346f5fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <d311d4de364a902ec0c0dc22079f8d73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34701000 - 0x3470bfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <4aa4e58f339a0344d7e86847e54c907d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34716000 - 0x3475afff  CoreMedia armv6  <7a9f4f7fe16ca10d9471c3248a103358> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34775000 - 0x347b1fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <4f3e66df51223dbc5232d7fb5c82113a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x347f5000 - 0x34812fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <7e34a4dd5c5b0400d10b01e998d5b2de> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34819000 - 0x3491ffff  MediaToolbox armv6  <ac956cf60c108068fbb7e90b0dc4792a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x34c0e000 - 0x34c14fff  MBX2D armv6  <6815ceba8853af0095f160b6d3c88937> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35522000 - 0x35525fff  ActorKit armv6  <c9043ba911b8bc95ffdc28f299caf609> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3553e000 - 0x3557bfff  CoreText armv6  <c584fae4a8877461b1fc27879ac762bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x355c8000 - 0x355ccfff  IOSurface armv6  <d2585af66f593d95adf6d1fab0181b1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x356e1000 - 0x3570bfff  MIME armv6  <4c2a074d32afce77a502835f5247874a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3580b000 - 0x35f5afff  WebCore armv6  <98f065e46e4c230bf091abaf6da60c16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x363b2000 - 0x363f7fff  iCalendar armv6  <51ba8755f9baa9d02517cd9e80a87d78> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36422000 - 0x3647cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <456f75f502443d281147f36f6ed4c3d3> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x36483000 - 0x36485fff  Notes armv6  <de15dc9ba3e18a4d962ceb876fc9a2b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3648a000 - 0x36493fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <2528ee7a4fd041090850f1845c393b84> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x36496000 - 0x364a6fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <44ee6b2c59cd5aa70d59f7d0d0d3b0b2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x364c1000 - 0x3655ffff  LDAP armv6  <c4d5a8dc449ceb89f87d531496c8e792> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LDAP.framework/LDAP
0x36596000 - 0x365c0fff  MobileQuickLook armv6  <86abc9b6fb4a37a971d7f6b290bb3e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x3661a000 - 0x36620fff  AccountSettings armv6  <14bd77206c288b9561e316817c89bf57> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x36646000 - 0x3664cfff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <7363aae30e9ba82d9eb1445d1d80398d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x367e7000 - 0x368c5fff  CoreData armv6  <0e55f80104ea5ac77a7640579f4a8ab8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x36ebb000 - 0x36ef9fff  DAVKit armv6  <edbd30dd8b12551043886ea0776575f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAVKit.framework/DAVKit
0x36f75000 - 0x36f84fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <58d1e0f460e85c5dd8cf63c7eb2fd1e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x36fac000 - 0x36fe7fff  ContentIndex armv6  <fff8b63e92ec9a8fc72d4c06d1228741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37124000 - 0x3712efff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <9adf227705e932c47e703f73ca1d87c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3748a000 - 0x374f3fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <44d54be7409eedbf35157cc538ea660b> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37c74000 - 0x37c74fff  Accelerate armv6  <e3325738fdc407edc125d921d2a90839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37cc8000 - 0x37d0bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <5632d3e7799c5c90540157938bce4b95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37d12000 - 0x37d12fff  vecLib armv6  <eb68bab288e9f047d876848490b162fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: are you using any libraries available from 3.1 and above only? you can use them, just make sure you weaklink them and check at runtime

Comment: What godexsoft said + you don't have to feel too bad about upping requirements to 3.1. 3.0 is ancient by now. But kudos if you still want to support it.

Comment: I'd like to support iOS 3.0 because it's the project's requirement. Can you help?

Comment: I second what @godexsoft said.  Make sure you aren't making any calls to libraries that are only available in 3.1 or later.  If you are, you can link, but don't make those specific calls if you are running 3.0.

Comment: See "Weak linking". Anything in the console log?

Comment: All I see is EXEC BAD ACCESS error displayed. Thanks.

Comment: After recreated the project. I see these lines in the console:          [Switching to process 10755 thread 0x0] 
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x0]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Cancelling call - objc code on the current thread's stack makes this unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is the solution.

**1 - Uncheck

Three20UI.xcodeproj

Three20UICommon.xcodeproj

Three20UINavigator.xcodeproj

from your target build
as highted in the picture.**

[image: Remove highlighted projects by unchecking them]
[image: Uncheck Three20UI]
[image: Uncheck Three20UICommon]

[image]

**2 -   Only add these Direct Dependencies to your project**

[image: Only add these Direct Dependencies to your project]

Answer (score 1):

The app crashes because of references to UISplitViewController in 1.0.5. You will need to either remove the references to UISplitViewController from Three20 or consider updating the code to load the class from NSClassFromString. I haven't had a chance to merge this fix into Three20 yet sadly.

Comment: Where do you see any mention of UISplitViewController? What is 1.0.5?

Comment: @Eiko:I did ask Jeff about Three20 v1.0.5, because I think this is the main reason the app crash on iOS 3.0. It happened after I integrate Three20 v1.0.5 into my project.

Comment: @fatherless: UISplitViewController is in UIKit.framework and I did make a link to UIKit.framework from |Required| to |Weak| => Still crash on iOS 3.0 works on iOS 3.1 and above.

Comment: @fatherless: could you give instructions on how to remove the references to UISplitViewController from Three20 because I don't seem to be able to modify Three20 source code and my app don't use UISplitViewController?